# Database Field is always empty in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports, dataset

I have inherited the task to add a field into an existing report.

This report is done in Visual Studio 2015 with crystal report. It has a data source linked to a [table] of a **dataset** (.xsd). But when it is loaded in C#, it has a different **datable** set as its data source.

```
_reportDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Reports/MyReport.rpt"));
_reportDocument.SetDataSource(mydatatable);
```

My field unfortunately belongs to a different [table] than the one already 'linked'. I eventually figured out I needed to add this new table to the dataset (it was not part of it at all!), and add this dataset's table to the datasource in the report designer in order for it to appear in the Field Explorer - 'Database Fields'.

---

This is where I tried about 5 thousands different ways to link the two tables together in order to get my missing field to show. No matter what I did, the [newfield] always resolutely remains empty in the report. What is more, the entire report appears empty if I do not set the link between the tables as 'OUTER'. (Which should not matter)

I eventually found the datatable ('mydatatable') code in C#, and modified it accordingly to hold my missing field. The data (in C# at least) is 100% correct when I check it at runtime. And yet changes nothing in the report itself.

*Issues::*

1) Everything from the first table is displayed fine. Nothing shows from the 'new' one I added to the dataset - ever.

2) The contents of the datatable set as data source in c# seem to have 0 impact on the report other than what records are shown.

---

**UPDATE**

---

So I've learned that the .XSD file served only as a kind of crystal report table definition for whatever DataSource is set for it. Additionnaly any attempts to use more than 1 table definition (more than 1 table from the xsd) seemed to fail, I'm not sure why - or why it allows you to link multiple ones if it will fail anyway.

With this knowledge, that the .XSD doesn't actually need to be linked to any database. I 'hardcoded' the column definitions I needed of that extra table, into the one already in use. After updating the dataset source in the crystal report, I added the new fields to the report, and the stored procedure data finally shows entirely.

Hopefully this can help anyone that stumbles into the same problem.

Comment: if you run the report in sql server do you see the data that you are missing in your report

Comment: @SimonPrice not sure what you mean by running it in sql. The datatable in c# however (the one also set as a datasource programmatically) does return a resultset from sql, and that data is all correct and contains all needed columns , both in sql and c#.

Comment: i expect it to return all the columns, but your saying the field is empty, do you get all of data you need.  If so, then its a binding issue in your crystal report, in the report is the datatype correct? is the there any formatting on the field or an expression thats not right?

Comment: i'm also expecting it to be a crystal report thing, there is no formatting, the link between the tables is done on differently named fields but the datatype is correct. the data in the database has been verified (by me), the join is definitly possible -> it works if I do a quick query with a normal join in sql